# X11 application (Matlab) won't respond to any keys/mouse, grey window on minimize (Snow Leopard)

Tags: macos, xorg, matlab, xquartz

Suddenly my Matlab (2012b) won't run. It starts fine but does not respond to any keys if I minimize it it comes back as just a grey window.
I tried reinstalling Matlab, then xQuartz (I actually uninstalled it and installed).
Any idea what can cause that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://derflounder.wordpress.com/2013/06/21/matlab-problems-after-java-for-mac-os-x-10-6-update-16-or-java-for-os-x-2013-004-are-installed/

Here you can find solution . It seems to java problem.
Due to X11 became open source, Apple do some mistake when update their programs.